# Undefined method `assessment' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting this following error:

```
undefined method `assessment' for nil:NilClass
```

My code below has the conditional unless to exclude if the method is nil, but is not working. I have also tried the if conditional as well, but not no avail.

I think I need to default to a number if assessment is nil, but unsure on how to do that.

The date is formatted in milliseconds: `1482985235000`

```
<% @sales.methods.each do |data| %>
  <%= Time.at(data.assessment.assessment_date/1000).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") unless data.assessment.assessment_date.nil? %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using safe navigation operator or have a chain of try.

`data.try(:assessment).try(:assessment_date).nil?`.

Or by using safe navigation operator.

`data&.assessment&.assessment_date.nil?`.

This error is generated when any method is called on nil. If data is nil then assessment will generate error if assessment is nil then assessment_date will. Either way you need to make sure both are present.
We generally don't use inline rescue and handle this type of scenarios by checking both objects. You can go with any of option or you can also check `data.assessment.present?  && data.assessment.assessment_date.present?`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are calling the method `assessment` on a nil... this means that the thing that is nil is `data`. Your conditional is checking whether `data.assessment.assessment_date` is nil... but it won't even get to the check for whether `assessment_date` is nil because it's already failing at `data.assessment`

Comment: Right. Removing the assessment_date from the conditional now gives me: undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Which I'm guessing because it's nil, it can't do the division.

Comment: Yes. `nil?` doesn't check all the way through the stack of message-passing, it only checks the last thing on the stack - you have to check each level just like @Manishh s examples using `try` or safe navigation

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem. Not sure if it's the best method, but it works. I added `rescue 0` to the end of the call.

```
<% @sales.methods.each do |data| %>
  <%= Time.at(data.assessment.assessment_date/1000).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") rescue 0 %>
<% end %>
```